# Android crash SQLiteDiskIOException

Tags: android

I have an `Exception` that appears only on the 'Gio Galaxy Android  2.3.3`.

[image]

Code:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    ...............................



    setContentView(R.layout.web_view_layout);

    WebView v = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.web_view);

    v.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

    CookieSyncManager.createInstance(this);
    CookieManager cookieManager = CookieManager.getInstance();
    cookieManager.removeAllCookie();

 ..............................

 }
```

Comment: Please do not link to externally hosted images. In case of error texts try to include them as text or if that is too complicated as image but uploaded to Stackoverflow.com

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7158434/webview-causes-sqlitediskioexception

Answer (score 0):

From what I've googled this occurs when a database becomes corrupt. I assume this `Gio` is the same device, over and over again, in your error log?

The strack trace is coming from the system, so I believe there's little you can do about it other than perhaps report the issue to Google.

[Source](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=7260)