# i am facing SQLiteDiskIOException: error code 10: disk

Tags: android

i am facing SQLiteDiskIOException: error code 10: disk I/O error when inserting images in to local DB.Please let me know if anyone knows about it

Comment: same as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3220482/sqlitediskioexception-in-android ?

Comment: Yes but its starts only after inserting 1000 images and it works fine in the tablets .im facing this only in phones and emulators.

Comment: Sorry, the accepted answer to the question Ivo Becker links to does not mention anything about the quantity of insert operations. It mentions multi-threading synchronization issues which are unfortunately likely to cause all different kinds of issues with SQLite on Android. Are you 100% sure that your app performs all write operations from 1 thread only and does not try to read or re-open the same database from another thread?

Comment: Yes i am sure .it performs all operations in one thread.

Comment: why are you inserting the images themselves instead of storing a path to the image?